# Is it possible to link to the scrapy docs using intersphinx?

Tags: scrapy, python-sphinx

I'm trying to link to the Scrapy documentation using intersphinx, but it does not appear to work.
I have the entry:

```
'scrapy': ('https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html', None)
```

in my `intersphinx_mapping`, but I get an error when building my docs saying:

```
intersphinx inventory 'https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html/objects.inv' not fetchable due to <class 'requests.exceptions.HTTPError'>: 404 Client Error: Not Found for url: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/index.html/objects.inv
```

Obviously this is not the correct link to use (or there isn't one).

I find it strange, because I also have w3lib in my intersphinx_mapping. w3lib is a scrapy subproject and it works just fine. So, I find it strange that intersphinx is possible with a subproject of scrapy, but not with the main project itself.

Comment: It looks like `https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/objects.inv` resolves, but is not on `en` local. Perhaps create an issue on the scrapy github repo as it looks to be improperly formatted.

Comment: @jwjhdev: what do you mean by "is not on `en` local"? The following `intersphinx_mapping` entry works for me: `'scrapy': ('https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest', None)`.

Comment: @mzjn yeah, you seem to be right. It was a mistake/oversight on my part to include the 'index.html'. The entry you describe works just fine.